# Spring not saving foriegn key of another table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a table name `City` which looks like

```
package com.spring.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Cities")
public class City {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "city_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "city")
    private Set<CompanyData> companyDatas = new HashSet<CompanyData>(0);

    public void setCompanyDatas(Set<CompanyData> companyDatas) {
        this.companyDatas = companyDatas;
    }

    public Set<CompanyData> getCompanyDatas() {
        return companyDatas;
    }

}
```

and I have another table name `Company`

```
package com.spring.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="CompanyDatas")
public class CompanyData {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    public void setCompanyName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return name;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_ID")
    private City city;

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }   
    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

}
```

and I am having a form to store Company Information but it is not saving the `city_ID` in table, although all other information is being stored accurately.

form looks like

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Company Data Manager | Company Data</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Company Data Manager</h2>

<form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="companyData">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="city"><spring:message code="label.city"/></form:label></td>
                <td><form:select name="city" path="city" >
                    <c:forEach items="${cityList}" var="city">
                        <option value="${city}">${city.name}
                    </c:forEach>
                    </form:select>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name"><spring:message code="label.name"/></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.addcompanyData"/>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where is the problem why it is not storing `city_ID` in `CompanyDatas` table. I am new to spring hibernate. Please guide me, Thanks

**EDIT :** Method in Company controller which saves company record

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/companyData/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCompany(@ModelAttribute("companyData")
    CompanyData companyData, BindingResult result) {
    companyDataService.addCompanyData(companyData);
    return "redirect:/companyData/index";
}
```

and the implementation is

```
public void addCompanyData(CompanyData companyData) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(companyData);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the method that saves the comapanyData ?

Comment: Yes Sure look at my edited controller part

Comment: you need to save the city object first. See my answer below.

Comment: But City is already saved in database of `Cities`, Only I need to show cities list in Company Form and saves its `id` in `CompanyDatas` table

Comment: @TonyGW he has already  the city , @Braham you need to get get `City` form the db  and based on city String in `CompanyDatas` (the Model)  then set it to CompanyData (the entity ) before saving it

Comment: If I am passing city id from form doesn't it automatically save the `city_ID` in `Company` Data?

Comment: no it doesn't , you have to pass the id then get the city form data base based on that Id and set city to company data

Comment: @BrahamShakti, with the id from the form, you need to retrieve the city object from database, and use the setter to set city to your companyData object.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dao class for saving city, you will need to first save the City object into your database, then iterate through the set: `Set<CompanyData> companyDatas`, save individual companyData

something like this:

```
// make sure you've set each companyData to be owned by the city object

city.getCompanyDatas.add(companyData);  // you will probably need to do this as many times as the size of the Set
companyData.setCity(city);   // set the owner to the city object

Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(city)           //save city object first so you will get the cityId for companyData
for (CompanyData cd : companyDatas)
{
    session.save(cd);
}
tx.commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

The Model of your Form `companyData` shoudln't be the same as your `Entity`.
    use a different Model class like `CompanyDataModel`

```
public class CompanyDataModel {
  private String name;
  private String city;
// GETTERS AND SETTERS

}
```

Your form should look like this :

```
<form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="companyDataModel">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="city"><spring:message code="label.city"/></form:label></td>
                <td><form:select name="city" path="city" >
                    <c:forEach items="${cityList}" var="city">
                        <option value="${city.id}">${city.name}
                    </c:forEach>
                    </form:select>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name"><spring:message code="label.name"/></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.addcompanyData"/>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
</form:form>
```

the Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/companyData/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCompany(@ModelAttribute("companyDataModel")
    CompanyDataModel companyDataModel, BindingResult result) {  
    companyDataService.addCompanyData(companyDataModel);
    return "redirect:/companyData/index";
}
```

the service methode to save the CompanyData :

```
public void addCompanyData(CompanyDataModel companyDataModel) {
CompanyData comData = new CompanyData();
       comData.setComapnyName(companyDataModel.getName());
       session = sessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       City city =  (City) session.get(City.class, Integer.parseInt(companyDataModel.getCity));
       campanyData.setCity(city);
       session.save(companyData);
 }
```